# Symfony2 - Doctrine Listeners

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

In my application I have listener that is reading annotations from model files (just like doctrine extensions Gedmo) but I dont understand one thing. 
In annotation driver there is a method named validateFullMetadata() and I have no idea when this method is called. 
I have discovered that DriverChain (from Gedmo) implements this method but its empty.

Can somebody explain me when this method is called and what is general purpose of using it? 
In my opinion this method is used to validate metadata values but I might be wrong. 
Also documentation says that it should be called formed from inherited classes if there were any. But I have no idea what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after deeper research I have the answer.

Method validateFullMetadata() should be used only if entity extends some fields from [MappedSuperclass](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses). But there is a small problem in gedmo mapping extension. When driver for annotations from Object Manager is DriverChain gedmo create it owns driver Chain.

Method is called but gedmo Gedmo/Mapping/Driver/Chain.php (Chain class) have this method empty (public function validateFullMetadata(data) {} ), without any code so it will be never called in driver from listener. 
The new issue is added at github, more information can be found [here](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/issues/199).